# Conditional design in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have 4 columns A-D, i want to do a conditional design for couples for all the columns together.

```
    A B C D
    1 2 3 4
    1 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4
```

In this example rows 1 and 3 will marked but not row 2 because column D is not the same.
How can i do this?

Comment: this makes no sense - "row...3 will marked but not row 3"

Comment: oh, sorry, i fixed it...

Comment: just to be clear... if a row has, for example, "4" in column D, the entire row gets marked? What you want is probably something like this. Using just the first row, conditional format D1 so that if it = 4, it's formatted. Then for cells A1,B1,C1, choose conditional format, dropdown to Formula Is, then have something like =$D1>3 (if D1 is greater than 3, apply formatting)

Comment: i want that all the columns A-D would be similar and then it would marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to see all rows that have more than 1 occurrence, you can do something like this...
Add a column with (column E)

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2)
```

then next to that

```
=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$4,E2)
```

Make sure to include the absolute references for the countif.  Then any row that is >1 means there is another duplicate row somewhere in the list.  Hope that's what you're looking for.